# Set Wi-Fi username/password in sensor (wifi module)

Tags: wifi, android-wifi, sensors, iot

**Background:**

I am developing a load cell sensor which will detect weight and send it to Server application.Project is related to IoT. This sensor should be connected to internet in order to send data to server. The sensor has wi-fi module which will take care of this communication.

**What I want to achieve :**

User should be able to set his own wi-fi username/password in the sensor device. for this, I am thinking of android app which can connect to sensor and send username/password to it. But I am not aware of standard procedures.

**Question:**
Can anyone tell me how do we ensure that end user can easily setup his own sensor by passing required data to it ? what is the standard procedure to achieve this ?

Comment: This is a rather broad question, and is not the best for Stack Overflow. But, there is no set standard procedure to perform this setup. You can use NFC, BLE, strobing a phones flash, or a on module method of data entry.

Comment: Thanks Sean. BLE and NFC both seem to work as per expectations :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use a NFC/BLE as suggested and/or put the device into AP mode serving a configure webpage as default. A computer, android, any device can connect to this AP and configure the sensor. Chromecast do something similar to this. It broadcasts so Android device can detect it, than it follows a Android app flow that should configure it to the WiFi desired and finally, it can be found at local WiFi.

Seems the best approach to me.